# lib.web.mvc installation issue with VS 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lib.web.mvc

I am getting the following error while installing the lib.web.mvc.6.8.2 package with **VS 2017**. It seems there is an issue with the dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc already installed:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

> **Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3' already exists in project** 'MyMVCApplication' Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.6708551

```
PM> Install-Package Lib.Web.Mvc -Version 6.8.2
```

> Attempting to gather dependency information for package
>   'Lib.Web.Mvc.6.8.2' with respect to project 'MyMVCApplication',
>   targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
>
> Gathering dependency information took 8,86 sec
>
> Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Lib.Web.Mvc.6.8.2'
>   with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
>
> Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
>
> Resolving actions to install package 'Lib.Web.Mvc.6.8.2'
>
> Resolved actions to install package 'Lib.Web.Mvc.6.8.2'
>
> Retrieving package 'Lib.Web.Mvc 6.8.2' from 'nuget.org'. Install
>   failed. Rolling back...
>
> **Package 'Lib.Web.Mvc.6.8.2 : Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc [4.0.0, 6.0.0)' does not exist in project 'MyMVCApplication'**
>
> Package 'Lib.Web.Mvc.6.8.2 : Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc [4.0.0, 6.0.0)' does
>   not exist in folder 'C:\Users\Cyberphil83\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\MyMVCApplication\packages'
>
> Executing nuget actions took 19,84 ms Install-Package : Could not
>   install package 'Lib.Web.Mvc 6.8.2'. You are trying to install this
>   package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2',
>   but  the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.At line:1  char:1
>   + Install-Package Lib.Web.Mvc -Version 6.8.2
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [github of this project](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc/), and it looks like it is targeting .NET 4.6:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

[Lib.Web.Mvc.csproj](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc/blob/master/Lib.Web.Mvc/Lib.Web.Mvc.csproj)

But your app is targeting 4.5.2.

So you have few options. One of them is to clone/fork this project and compile targeting 4.5.2. Or simply change your app to 4.6 (if possible?).

Comment: Hi Jerry, Indeed it is the root cause. I switched my project to .NET 4.6 and the package is installing correctly now! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since v6.8.0 release `Lib.Web.Mvc` requires .NET 4.6+ as it requires HTTP/2 support.

There is a [v6.7.x](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc/tree/v6.7.x) branch which is fix-only branch supporting .NET 4.0+.

If you want to stick to .NET 4.5.2 you will have to use latest 6.7.x version:

```
PM> Install-Package Lib.Web.Mvc -Version 6.7.1
```

Alternative is to upgrade your project to .NET 4.6+.

Comment: Got it! I upgraded my project to .NET 4.6 and Lib.Web.Mvc is correctly installed now. Thanks for these clarifications.